# Show a horizontally large background in back of Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, horizontalscrollview

I have a background image with a long width which I want to be in back of a Recyclerview with 8 item in it(Recyclerview). This is possible only with a horizontal-scrollview which I coded below but Is there any way to not use horizontal scrollview and have a same result?

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/HSV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:paddingLeft="2.5dp"
            android:paddingRight="2.5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

with the above code I have the desired output, but as I remove the HorizontalScrollView The image is compressing in width and loose its shape I want the image scroll as I scroll the recyclerview 
That is The picture I want:
[![in Background is the aforementioned image and this eight Item are in recycler view and I want as the items finishing the background image is finishing too.
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KP1sH.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KP1sH.jpg)

Comment: GIve out a link or demo of what you want. That'd be helpful.

Comment: @Alok The demo is attached

Comment: I have answered your query, please look into it and tell me how it goes for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Design like this in layout.And pass **layout of card in image** to adapter in Android.Set **background** to Constraint layout ore Recyclerview. **When you have Recyclerview no need to add Horizontal Scrollview. Just pass Layout manager as Horizontal**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/secondaryColor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>idget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: No this can't solve my problem, as I said without Horizontal scrollview my long background compressed and only recycler scrolled

Comment: Did you make it. I think you are supporting tab with that design and truly you need very large image and convert in to WebP. Consider an high resolution image that support 10.1 tablet and convert it to WebP and use it

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if I have got your query right, so you want your `RecyclerView` to be scrolling horizontally. I would suggest to use the `LinearLayoutManager` for the same, so that you can pass the Scrolling constant to Horizontal in the arguments of LinearLayoutManager.

To read about it, please go ahead and read it [LinearLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#LinearLayoutManager(android.content.Context,%20int,%20boolean))

And when you get it, just do it like this in you `Java Class`.

```
RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));
```

I have this youtube link for you too, if you don't get it what you want. Here you will get the full demo of how to do it, and achieve it. [Horizontal RecyclerView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94rCjYxvzEE)

I hope that will answer your query. Thanks :)

Comment: No that is definitely isn't my problem. I want a way to have a horizontal Recyclerview with a horizontally big background image. As the Recyclerview Item finishes, the image finishes too. The background with the condition I have mentioned is my concern